# Why can't I omit the implicit parameter here?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

My codes looks like this

```
  def okJsonify[T](data: T)(implicit tjs: Writes[T]): Result = Results.Ok(toJson(data)(tjs))
```

And the definition of `toJson`: `play-json_2.11-2.3.7-sources.jar!/play/api/libs/json/Json.scala`

```
  def toJson[T](o: T)(implicit tjs: Writes[T]): JsValue = tjs.writes(o)
```

I found I can write the codes shorter like this(omit the `(tjs)`)

```
  def okJsonify[T](data: T)(implicit tjs: Writes[T]): Result = Results.Ok(toJson(data))
```

but can't be shorten further like this:

```
  def okJsonify[T](data: T): Result = Results.Ok(toJson(data))
```

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be obvious: `toJson` requires a `Write[T]` parameter. Since it's implicit, it can be passed implicitly, so either `toJson(data)(tjs)` (explicit) and `tJson(data)` (implicit) works. But if you don't *have* a `Writes[T]` value to pass, such as the last case, there's nothing to be passed explicitly or implicitly.